# Composer на win 7

Tags: windows, ssl, composer

хочу установить https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer
при указании php.exe вываливается такая ошибка

> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script
>   again:
>
> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS
>   transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or
>   recompile php with --with-openssl

я использую http://open-server.ru/ и вряд ли смогу перкомпилировать экзешник.

Как быть?

вот тут вроде чувак создал ссылку в c\windows на php.ini https://plutov.by/post/composer_openserver
но у меня вылазит туева хуча ошибок что экстеншенов нет

в open server то ssl скорее всего включен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вот при попытке установки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отердактировать дефолтный файл конфигурации (легко находится в контекстном меню OS), там раскомментировать экстенжн.

Comment: можно по подробнее. ничего не понял

Comment: Найти в трее опенсервер - открыть меню - найти "конфигурация" - щелкнуть по PHP - в открывшемся файле найти закомментированную строку с openssl-расширением (не верю, что оно там не стоит) - раскомментировать ее - сохранить - перезапустить сервер

Comment: extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: `php --ini` чтобы проверить, какой конфиг он использует (есть вероятность, что не тот)

Comment: где это писать?

Comment: D:\open\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.4\php.ini странно - он же из config должен брать. как это поправить?

Comment: и вообще такое ощущение что виноват во всем файл imagick

Comment: интересно, может полная переустановка поможет

Comment: Нет, это у него нормальное поведение. Пока что проще указанный файл отредактировать.

Comment: так это наверно баг open server что у него с imagickom косяк

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле не нужно устанавливать Conposer в OpenServer, он там уже установлен по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут есть статья по поводу устноавки composer на OpenServer
http://nikolaev-web.ru/blog/installing_the_composer_on_openServer/

Может поможет

Comment: перенесите основные тезисы статьи в ответ - если статью удалят, ваш ответ в текущем виде потеряет ценность